# display new line in report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

hello 
i'm building new report using report builder
i need to retrieve my data from database and displa it in a table. all thing is allright but i have one problem.
i have one feild contain new line ( char (13) ) from data base (the char(13) is contained in the data retrieved from database)
but the report builder didn't display the new line in the output report

i'm using mssql 2008 R2 the data are displayed in multiple line in mssql and visual studio

any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as I understood, MS Report Builder does not understand special symbols.
Instead for new line you should use "vbCrLf" constant (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255261(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `char(13)` with `<br/>` somewhere before you display it.